# Como puedo deshabilitar un jtextfield por diez segundos en java

Tags: java, jtextfield, time

Hola me podrian indicar cual es la mejor manera de deshabilitar un jtextfield despues de que el usuario presione enter por un determinado tiempo como 10 seg

Gracias

Comment: Muy buenas, deberias poner el código con lo que has intentado para que la comunidad pueda guiarte mejor. Te recomendo que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: buenas aun no lo intentaba con nada, solo queria saber cual consideraban es la mejor opcion para deshabilitar por tiempos ya sea textfield, botones etc... gracias por la informacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución es crear un timer

```
public class Tiempo extends JFrame {

    private JTextField txtTexto;
    private Timer timer, cuenta;
    private JLabel lbCuenta;
    private int contador;

    public Tiempo() throws HeadlessException {
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);

        txtTexto = new JTextField(50);
        txtTexto.setBounds(100, 100, 180, 20);
        contador = 0;
        lbCuenta = new JLabel("Segundos: " + contador);
        lbCuenta.setBounds(100, 80, 80, 20);
        //Se crea el evento para el enter
        txtTexto.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtTexto.setEnabled(false);//Se desactiva el JTextField
                txtTexto.repaint();//Se repinta para actualizar
                timer.start();//Comienza la cuenta
                cuenta.start();//Esto es solo para la cuenta de los seg
            }
        });

        //Es solo para mostrar la cuenta de los segundos
        cuenta = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                contador++;
                lbCuenta.setText("Segundos: " + contador);
                if (contador > 9) {
                    cuenta.stop();
                }
            }
        });

        //El timer se activa despues de 10000 milisegundos equivalente a 10s
        timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtTexto.setEnabled(true);//Despues de los 10s se activa
                txtTexto.repaint();//Se repinta para actualizar
                timer.stop();//Se detiene el timer
            }
        });

        add(lbCuenta);
        add(txtTexto);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tiempo();
    }
}
```

Cualquier duda, me avisas.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la info

Answer (score 1):

Prueba un Timmer. Algo así valdría.

```
.....
    textField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                  deshabilitar();
                }
            });
....
void deshabilitar()
{
textField.setEnabled(false);
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(100000, new ActionListener ()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
            textField.setEnabled(true);
     }
}); 
}
```

Mas ejemplos en: http://www.chuidiang.org/java/timer/timer.php

Comment: Falta lo de presionar enter, que supongo es la parte complicada del problema.

Comment: No, simplemente pones  que el código que te he puesto arriba, se ejecute al realizar un actionPerformed. Edito el ejemplo.

Comment: Nice!! nunca había utilizado un ActionListener en un JTextfiel, no sabía que reaccionaba con un enter.

Comment: Gracias por la info lo hice algo similar a esto, tambien se puede ralizar con hilos